# RelativeLayout Scrollable

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, scrollable

I have tried many times to aligh the elements in my RelativeLayout but I dont get the result I expected that is:

[image]

I'd like to align the first button to top right and then I have multiple Textview and I want all of them Scrollable, but when I insert the tag  I get an error, this is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/RL01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="5dp">

     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnBrowser"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Browser"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            >
    </Button>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAuthor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#143781"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnBrowser"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#8D89B3"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtAuthor">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDate">
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle">
    </TextView>

    <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnReply"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Reply"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/txtMsg"
          android:layout_centerInParent="@+id/txtMsg">

    </Button>
       </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ScrollView` does not allow more than one direct child, that's why you getting error. So you try as follows:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Button" />

     </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant put more than one widget in a scrollview. To this you have to wrap your widget with a view. like below

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBrowser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Browser" >

        </Button>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAuthor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnBrowser"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="#143781"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtAuthor"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#8D89B3"
            android:textSize="14dp" android:text="Text"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:text="Text">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dp" android:text="Text">
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMsg"
            android:layout_centerInParent="@+id/txtMsg"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Reply" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `scrollview` inside `relativelayout`. You have to add `Relativelayout` inside `scrollview` to get results. and one more thing `scrollview` can contains only one child at a time so add `relativelayout` into `scrollview` and see the difference