# Relative layout scrollable issue

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout and i want it to make it scrollable, i made it too but the problem is it is scrollable even if it is not needed...

there are links that i refer but not worked in my case

[how to make a relative layout scrollable when it has many children views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210508/how-to-make-a-relative-layout-scrollable-when-it-has-many-children-views)

[RelativeLayout Scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659442/relativelayout-scrollable)

here is my layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ab" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="135dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/r" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rgpvtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="RGPV Digest"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#5C9E70"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/compu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rgpvtext"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Computer Science"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/calc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/compu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Calculator"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/calc"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Interview Question"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Programs"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/prog"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="About"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#5B9D79"
        android:paddingTop="6dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put all items in a root item like `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc. And if you want to use `ScrollView` as a root item, you have to declare one more item in it like `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` then put all items in it.

I try to make it work as you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ab">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="135dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/r"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rgpvtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="RGPV Digest"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#5C9E70"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/compu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rgpvtext"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:text="Computer Science"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/calc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/compu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Calculator"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/calc"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Interview Question"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Programs"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/prog"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="About"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="24sp" />


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="#5B9D79"
                android:layout_below="@+id/abo"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but it is still not working, please check my editing

Comment: Listview has its own scroll. Maybe you should remove your scrollview because its useless. Your listview will scroll when list items are added.

Answer (score 1):

I made it scrollable....below code is working fine...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ab" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="135dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rgpvicon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rgpvtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="RGPV Digest"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/compu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rgpvtext"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Computer Science"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/calc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/compu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Calculator"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/calc"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Interview Question"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Programs"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/prog"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="About"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@drawable/texteff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#5B9D79"
    android:paddingTop="6dp" />
```